# Est-ce que c'est courant de demander "vous êtes de France?"

Tags: usage, verbes

Quand je rencontre des personnes en train de parler français, je leur demande parfois « Vous venez de France ? », et d'habitude on me regarde comme si j'étais fou et on me demande de répéter. Je ne sais pas pourquoi car mon accent est assez bon, je crois.

Je me demande si l'on devrait ou même pourrait dire « Vous êtes de France ? » à la place.

Est-ce que ça se dit, « être de [pays] » ? En anglais, bien sûr, on dirait simplement *You're from France?* plutôt que *You come from France?*

Est-ce que l'expression « venir de [pays] » est inhabituelle ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« Venir de France » et « être de France » ne sont pas idiomatiques.

On dit simplement:

> — Vous êtes Français ?

Comment: Oh why didn't anyone ever tell me this...

Comment: Comme ce n'est pas idiomatique le sens littérale "Venir de France", est étrange si la question est posée sur le territoire Français.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas et l'on peut très bien venir de France sans parler un mot de français, étant par exemple de passage à une frontière ou dans un aéroport.

Answer (score 1):

On dit généralement "vous venez de France ?" lorsque quelqu'un vient d'arriver et que vous vouliez lui demander d'où il vient. Si c'est pour demander son origine, il vaut mieux dire comme dans la réponse de jlliagre "vous êtes français ?" ou "Vous êtes de la France ?"

Comment: « Vous êtes de la France ? » n'est pas idiomatique en France sauf si une précision est ajoutée à France et plutôt dans une affirmation qu'une question. Par exemple « Vous êtes de la France des nantis ! » ou « Vous êtes de la France d'en bas ! ».